# Measurability on finite measure space. Show that f is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable.

Tags: measure-theory, complex-numbers

Ok, so I'm given a finite measure space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$

Let $E\in\mathcal{A}$ be such that $\mu(E)\neq0$ and $\mu(E^c)\neq0$

Define a $\sigma$-algebra by $\mathcal{G}$={$\emptyset,E,E^c,\Omega$}

Show that $$f:\Omega\to\mathbb {C}$$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable 
if and only if

$$f=a\mathbb1_{E} + b\mathbb1_{E^c}$$ for some complex numbers $a,b\in\mathbb{C}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I preassume that $\mathbb C$ is equipped with a $\sigma$-algebra, such that every subset of $\mathbb C$ that is a singleton belongs to it. Consequently the fibers of a measurable function having $\mathbb C$ as codomain are measurable sets.

---

If $f=a1_E+b1_{E^c}$ for $a,b\in\mathbb C$ then preimages under $f$ will evidently be elements of $\mathcal G$ so $f$ will be measurable.

If conversely $f$ is $\mathcal G$-measurable and takes at least $3$ distinct values in $\mathbb C$ then $\Omega$ can be written as union of $3$ disjoint non-empty measurable subsets, i.e. elements of $\mathcal G$. This is not possible, so we conclude that $f$ takes at most $2$ values. This leads to $f=a1_E+b1_{E^c}$.